# Using Powershell to make USB Bootable Drive

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate someone taking a ISO and making that into a bootable USB. I need help with that last command in the script which is xcopy.  How can I copy all the files from the user imputed $ISO to the USB drive X:? I am having issues using "$ISO" and ":" in a path. The last command needs work cause currently it errors out.

```
Write-Host "Please mount your ISO and insert your USB stick"
$ISO = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter your mounted ISO drive letter'
Write-Host "Your mounted drive letter is seleted as $ISO"
Get-Disk
$USBDisk = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter your USB Disk Number from above'
Get-Disk $USBDisk | Clear-Disk -RemoveData
New-Partition -DiskNumber $USBDisk -Size 30000 MB -IsActive -DriveLetter X | Format-Volume -FileSystem FAT32 -NewFileSystemLabel Win10
xcopy $ISO:\* X:\ /S
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
xcopy ${ISO}:\* X:\ /S
```

This is an alternate method of referencing a variable and is useful when you need a trailing colon and don't want to confuse the parser with looking for a variable namespace.

Comment: Ahh this is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That is not the *only* meaning of the `${}` construct.  Please see `Get-Help about_Variables` under the heading "VARIABLE NAMES THAT INCLUDE SPECIAL CHARACTERS".

Comment: @BaconBits It's just an implementation detail, but nonetheless just noise for this user